# How to extract data from 3d model to a data table that is easy to read for machine learning algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, data, 3d-reconstruction

I want to do something similar to Point Cloud. What I am NOT trying to do is to recognize objects or reconstruct them. I have a 3d file and I want to somehow read the data to use it in machine learning algorithm.

Where to look for info?
Googling just gives a lot of examples of shape recognition and 2d to 3d shape reconstruction. I want it other way from 3d to 1d data

Comment: add a description of this 3D file